# Memory error: Dereference null pointer/ SSE misalignment

Tags: c++, linux

I'm compiling a program on remote linux server. The program compiled. However when I run it the program ends abruptly. So I debugged the program using DDT. It spits out the following error:

```
    Process 0:
    Memory error detected in ClassName::function (filename.cpp:6462).
    Thread 1 attempted to dereference a null pointer or execute an SSE instruction with an 
    incorrectly aligned memory address (the latter may sometimes occur spuriously if guard 
    pages are enabled)
    Tip: Use the stack list and the local variables to explore your program's current 
    state and identify the source of the error.
```

Can anyone please tell me what exactly this error means?

The line where the program stops looks like this:

```
    SumUtility = ParaEst[0] + hhincome * ParaEst[71] + IsBlack * ParaEst[61] + IsBachAss * (ParaEst[55]);
```

This is within a switch case.

These are the variable types

```
    vector<double> ParaEst;
    double hhincome;
    int IsBlack, Is BachAss;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Incorrectly aligned memory address raises `SIGBUS`.
Dereference a null pointer should cause `SIGSEGV`.
But there isn't enough info to answer your question.  Run under `valgrind` or `GDB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that:

1. ParaEst is NULL or a bad Pointer
2. ParaEst's individual array values are not aligned to 16-byte boundaries, required for SSE.
3. hhincome, IsBlack, or IsBachAss are not aligned to 16-byte boundaries and are SSE type values.
4. SumUtility is not aligned to 16-bytes and is a SSE type field.

If you could post the assembly code of the exact line that failed along with the register values of that assembler line, we could tell you exactly which of the above conditions have failed.  It would also help to see the types of each variable shown to help narrow root the cause.

Comment: @Dorgan: I have added the variable type. One reason I could not post the values at the time of error was because I'm debugging in DDT and it does not seem to display the contents of a 'vector' type. It just shows that the <expression cannot be evaluated>

Comment: Given that, the vector needs to be declared 16-byte aligned with some sort of compiler directive.  That should fix this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... The problem finally got fixed.

The issue was that the expression where the code was breaking down was in a newly defined function. However for some weird reason running the make-file did not incorporate these changes and was still compiling using the previously compiled .o file. This resulted in garbage values being assigned to the variables within this new function. To top things off the program calls this function as a first step. Hence there was this systematic breakdown. The technical aspect of this was what Michael alluded to.

After this I would always recommend to use a make clean option in the make file. The issue of why running the make file is failing to compile the modified source file is an issue that definitely warrants further discussion.

Thanks for the responses!!